# exporting a csv file in PHP and JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

I'm trying to implement a tool to export data from a research website as a `csv` file. In my `download` controller, I have:

```
public function export(){
    $data = array(
          array('Name', 'Age', 'City'),
          array('Philippe', '23', 'Palo Alto'),
          array('John', '30', 'San Francisco'),
          array('Paul', '20', 'Los Angeles')
    );

    header('Content-type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');

    $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    foreach( $data as $line ) {
        fputcsv( $fp, $line );
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
```

and from my `view`, I do:

```
function download() {
     $('#download').empty().html('<img src="<?php echo base_url();?>/images/loader.gif" />');
     $.post('<?php echo base_url();?>/index.php/download/export');
}
```

and `download()` is fired up when the user click to a button with a `onclick='download()'`.
However, I'm not seen the file being downloaded, nor a error message. When I look into my `firebug` console, I see:

> 200 OK        29ms     jquery.min.js (line 4) HeadersPostResponseCookies
>
> Name,Age,City Philippe,23,"Palo Alto" John,30,"San Francisco"
>   Paul,20,"Los Angeles"

What am I missing? 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't actually want an AJAX request here. You want to redirect your user to the file with:

```
window.location = '<?php echo base_url();?>/index.php/download/export';
```

The AJAX request is telling the server to send the data back to the script's success method. Since it's a download, the redirect won't make you leave the page so you can use this method without confusing your user.