# Export All Records, Ignoring Pagination

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, datatables

Currently I'm using Datatables with pagination. Now I recently added the Datatable.buttons library to use Export to Excel option. Now this functionality works fine but it only exports the first 10 rows of the page I'm currently in due to pagination. Now if I remove the limit in my model class, it will export all the entries which is what I want but it also gets rid of the pagination which decreases my site performance. The following is my current AJAX call code for getting Datatable data:

I'm excepting to download all the rows of data without pagination on excel button download , i tried using export option also but still downloading first page of data.

`

```
const table = new DataTable("#ajax-datatables-customers", {
                    processing: true,
                    serverSide: true,
                    dom: "Brt<'row'<'col-4 pt-2'l><'col-4 text-center'i><'col-4 text-center'p>>",
                    serverMethod: 'post',
                    buttons: [
                            {
                                extend: 'excel',
                                filename: 'hr_pivot_customers_' + new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10),
                                exportOptions: {
                                    modifier: {
                                        page: 'all'
                                    },
                                    columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
                                }
                            },
                        ],
                   
                    ajax: {
                        url :'<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?datatables',                        
                    },
                    columns: [
                        { data: 'id'},
                        { data: null},
                        { data: 'email'},
                        { data: 'phone'},
                        { data: 'status'},
                        { data: 'status'}
                    ],
                     columnDefs : [
                    {
                        targets:1,
                        data: null,
                        
                        render: function (data, type, row) {
                            var firstname = row.firstname;
                            var lastname = row.lastname;
                            if (firstname && lastname) {
                                return firstname + ' ' + lastname;
                                } 
                            else if (firstname) {
                                return firstname;
                                } 
                            else if (lastname) {
                                return lastname;
                                } 
                            else {
                                return '';
                                }
                        }
                    },
 ],
                drawCallback : function( settings ) { }
                })
```

Comment: Have you tried setting serverSide = false? (Note: it will increase server response time because it brings all the data)

Comment: @ZaidMalek . i tried the serverside= false. then on refresh it gives alert msg as  ( DataTables warning: table id=ajax-datatables-customers - Invalid JSON response). For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1 . After closing the alert msg it still loading

Comment: Another solution could be using a custom export button and separate ajax call for it. In which you will have to pass non paginated data. If you want I can help you with that.

Comment: @ZaidMalek , pls help bro . if i use separate ajax call for excel download without limit and offset pagination , then if i use search filter in current query will not be affected?

Comment: You can generate a csv with help of fopen and fputcsv (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501463/creating-csv-file-with-php) from sever side and download it using js. please specify whether you are using core php or any php framework so I can help you furthermore

Comment: @ZaidMalek , i am using code php . in datatables function using ajax call to send the data into another page and excel download how?

Comment: you can try [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11977062/exporting-a-csv-file-in-php-and-javascript) in backend side if you still need more help you can let me know

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have loaded all the required datatable js library assets.

Please remove below line,

```
serverSide: true
```

This will work fine, if you are fetching dataset with PHP ajax script with all data
(For e.g., SQL Query as `SELECT * FROM customers;`)

Make sure you are not applying filters on PHP side, otherwise you need to provide datatables.php file and HTML view file for further investigation.

I have tested with below version configs:
Datatables: 1.10.19
Datatables buttons: 1.5.6